# Static Const object

Tags: c++, static, struct, initialization, constants

I'm having trouble initializing a static const struct element.  I am using NTL's polynomials mod p (ZZ_pX.h) library and I have need for the following struct:

```
struct poly_mat {
    ZZ_pX a,b,c,d;
    void l_mult(const poly_mat& input); // multiplies by input on the left
    void r_mult(const poly_mat& input); // multiplies by input on the right

    static const poly_mat IDENTITY;  // THIS IS THE PART I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH
}
```

So a poly_mat is a 2x2 matrix of polynomials.  I have multiply operations, and in the functions I'm writing I often have to return the identity matrix a=1,b=0,c=0,d=1.  I can't get the static const poly_mat IDENTITY line to work, so right now I have a function return_id() which outputs the identity matrix, but I'd like to not have to compute a new identity matrix each time I want to return it.

Is there a way to initialize the static const poly_mat IDENTITY in my cpp file so that I can just refer to the same copy of the identity matrix rather than having to generate a new one each time.  It's complicated by the fact that the matrix elements are polynomials mod p, and p isn't chosen until the first line of my int main().  Maybe I have to make IDENTITY a pointer to something and initialize it once I set p?  Can IDENTITY then be static const?  Am I making sense?

Thanks.

Comment: You may get more responses if you add a tag for the relevant language.  You also may want to specify the error you get when you try to compile.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is suggested by Meyers.  Simply use a function like you have done but make the local variable in the function `static` and return a reference to it.  `static` ensures that only a single object is created.

Here's an example showing that `theIdentity()` returns the same object each time.

```
#include <iostream>

struct poly_mat {
  int x;
  static const poly_mat & TheIdentity();
};

const poly_mat & poly_mat::TheIdentity() {
  static struct poly_mat theIdentity = {1};
  return theIdentity;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "The Identity is " << poly_mat::TheIdentity().x 
    << " and has address " << &poly_mat::TheIdentity() << std::endl;
  struct poly_mat p0 = {0};
  struct poly_mat p1 = {1};
  struct poly_mat p2 = {2};
  std::cout << "The Identity is " << p0.TheIdentity().x 
    << " and has address " << &p0.TheIdentity() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "The Identity is " << p1.TheIdentity().x 
    << " and has address " << &p1.TheIdentity() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "The Identity is " << p2.TheIdentity().x 
    << " and has address " << &p2.TheIdentity() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "You cannot have `poly_mat` have a `poly_mat` as a member because `poly_mat` is not yet declared."  Not true: a `static` member declaration can have incomplete type.  (But its definition can't.)

Comment: @aschepler I didn't realize that but now that I think about it, that makes sense.  Thanks for correcting.